# If the variance of a random variable $X$ exists, show $E(X^2)\geq [E(X)]^2$.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Is the following proof valid?

---

Let's try a proof by contradiction.

Suppose $E(X^2)<[E(X)]^2$. Since $[E(X)]^2\geq 0$, then $E(X^2)<0$.

But in the discrete case, if $p(x)$ is the p.m.f. of $X$ and $\mathscr{A}$ is the space of $X$, then
$$
E(X^2)=\sum_{x\in \mathscr{A}}x^2p(x)
$$
We know for all $x\in \mathscr{A}$ that $p(x)\geq 0$ and $x^2\geq 0$, and thus $x^2p(x)\geq 0$. We must have then
$$
E(X^2)=\sum_{x\in \mathscr{A}}x^2p(x)\geq 0
$$
which contradicts the conclusion that $E(X^2)<0$. It must be true, then, that $E(X^2)\geq [E(X)]^2$.

Similar proof can be shown for the continuous case. Did I prove this correctly?

Comment: No. $E(X^2)$ is always positive. If you have $a < b$, with $b \geq 0$ it does not imply that $a < 0$.

Comment: $[E(X)]^2 \geq 0$ and $E(X^2) <[E(X)]^2$ does not imply $E(X^2)<0$. This is like deducing from $2<3$ and $3\geq 0$ that $2<0$.

Comment: Hint: $\text{Var}(X)$ can be expressed also as $E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

Comment: You cannot split the proof into discrete and continuous cases. You have to prove th result for a genearl r.v.  Read about Holder/Cauchy-Schwarz ineqlality.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone; I should've looked at some cases to see that the implication was false. I'll try to redo the proof using a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I guess I had to use the original definition of $Var(X)$ where
$$
Var(X)=E[(X-\mu)^2]
$$
With $\mu=E(X)$, we have
$$
(X-\mu)^2\geq 0 \rightarrow\\
X^2-2X\mu+\mu^2\geq0 \rightarrow\\
E(X^2-2X\mu+\mu^2)\geq0 \rightarrow\\
E(X^2)-2\mu^2+\mu^2=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2\geq0 \rightarrow\\
E(X^2)\geq[E(X)]^2
$$
Completing the proof.

Comment: That's precisely the way to go. For completeness you should note $\mu = \mathsf E(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Jensen’s Inequality states that, for a convex function $g$ and random variable
$X$:
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] \geq g(E[X])$$

This inequality holds for any convex function. Note the similarity between this inequality and the definition of variance in terms of expectations.

**Added**

Recall that \begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=E([X-E(X)]^2)\\
&= E(X^2 - 2XE(X) + E(X)^2) \\
&= E(X^2) - 2E(X)^2 + E(X)^2 \\
&= E(X^2) - E(X)^2. \end{align}

Since $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ is always positive i.e
$$ \operatorname{Var}(X) \ge 0.$$

$$ 0 \le \operatorname{Var}(X) = E([X-E(X)]^2) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2. $$

Then,
$$ E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \geq 0 $$
Hence,
$$ E(X^2) \geq E(X)^2   $$.

Comment: So in this case, $g(X)=X^2$. Not sure what a convex function is. I just looked through my analysis textbook and found that a function $g$ in $(a,b)$ is said to be $\mathit{convex}$ if $g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(y)$ whenever $a<x<b, a<y<b, 0<\lambda <1$. Why is Jensen's Inequality specific to a convex function?

Comment: To use Jensen's inequality, we need to determine if a function $g$ is convex and yes, we need $g(X)=X^2$. If $n=2$, for example, your statement is the definition of convex functions. You can extend it to higher values of $n$ by induction. Now, consider a discrete random variable $X$ with $n=2$ possible values $x1$, $x2$. In your statement, we can choose $\lambda_{i}=P(X=x_i)=P_{X}(x_{i})$. Then, the left-hand side of the inequality becomes $g(EX)$ and the right-hand side becomes $E[g(X)]$.

Comment: @Ash Jensen's inequality is correct *in the other direction* for concave functions, so it is important that you use convex functions.